# Concat the values using the case condition

Tags: sql, hive, impala

```
select
case when concat('ACC','-',NVL(trim(bvmo.booking),''),'-',NVL(trim(bvmo.org),''),'-',NVL(trim(bvma.sparm),''),'-',NVL(trim(bvmo.id),'')  like 'ACC--%' then
 NULL ELSE concatconcat('ACC','-',NVL(trim(bvmo.booking),''),'-',NVL(trim(bvmo.org),''),'-',NVL(trim(bvma.sparm),''),'-',NVL(trim(bvmo.id),'') END AS Parent_id
from bvmo
```

### output:

```
 Parent-id
:----------:
ACC-1123-1344--
ACC-4567-6528--
ACC-7890-9827--
ACC-1143-8079--
ACC-1883-8944--
```

am expecting as the below output where i can remove the "-" in above case condition in which the values are not appearing in respective columns

### Expected output:

```
 Parent-id
:----------:
ACC-1123-1344
ACC-4567-6528
ACC-7890-9827
ACC-1143-8079
ACC-1883-8944
```

Comment: Depending on your data, it may be unwise to omit the `-` delimeters when fields are empty. If empty fields would always be later in the chain than any that are completed, then you're fine, but if a blank could be in the middle of the list, then you won't necessarily be able to tell what the concatenated value really means as it could have been constructed is one of several ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat_ws`. It should take care of nulls in the way you wanted.

```
select
    concat_ws('-', 'ACC', trim(bvmo.booking), trim(bvmo.org), trim(bvma.sparm), trim(bvmo.id)) AS Parent_id
from bvmo
```